# Implementing sessions > 4K in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

As I am setting up a new application using rails 4 and discover that active record store is deprecated.
I have sessions which always exceed 4kb, I assume that now need to use mem cached.
Does this require the dalli gem? Can somebody please give me some advice in setting this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It got moved to a gem: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

See [Extraction of features to gems](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#extraction-of-features-to-gems) in the edge guide.

The reason it was removed is mentioned in [this post](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/activerecord-sessionstore-gem-extraction-rails-4-countdown-to-2013):

> it isn't scalable. ... Once your application receives a large amount of
>   traffic, the sessions database table is continuously bombarded with
>   read/write operations.

So, if scalibility and performance are important, you might want to look at other ways to manage that data.